# Django async acount takes forever to execute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio

Consider a django rest framework application which calls an async function like;

```
class SomeViewSet(ListUpdateViewSet):
    @action(
        methods=["GET"],
        url_path=r"count-async",
        detail=False
    )
    def get_count_async(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('starting')

        t = asyncio.run(self.aget_count_async(request, *args, **kwargs))
        print('ending')

        return Response(data={

        })

    async def aget_count_async(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('before getting count')
        my_count = await User.objects.filter(id="1").acount()
        print('after getting count')
        return my_count
```

However whenever I run the endpoint I notice the logs show "before getting count", yet minutes later it is still running and no "after getting count" is being shown.

How can I debug this and what could possibly be the cause?

Comment: I don't think you should be executing the function using `asyncio.run`, you should just `await` it and make `get_count_async` an `async def`. You're probably messing with Django's internal asyncio loop.

Comment: @deceze the problem is then that this error occurs:  AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>` 
HTTP GET /api/v1/some/count-async/ 500 [0.51, 127.0.0.1:51526]
Which is part of django rest framework tests.